# can't open a receiver bound to application header x-match expression

Tags: amqp, qpid, rhea

I'm using rhea (https://github.com/amqp/rhea), a node.js library to develop AMQP 1.0 clients.

I'm trying to adapt https://github.com/amqp/rhea/tree/master/examples/selector example using an **x-match** expression instead of a JMS expression.

The purpose is to implement an **header routing** mechanism based on a AMQP 1.0 compliant broker (ActiveMQ, Qpid, ...).

I tried this code in the appropriate section in recv.js:

```
connection.open_receiver({
    source: {
        address: 'amq.match',
        filter: {
            'x-match': 'all',
            value: {
                'nat': 'it',
                'prod': 'a22'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Received a connection error "Expected value type is 'Filter' but got 'String' amqp:decode-error" from Qpid Java broker (rel. 7.1.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer received on rhea github repo:

https://github.com/amqp/rhea/issues/200#issuecomment-469220880

> The filter needs to be a described value. Try something like this:

```
connection.open_receiver({
    source: {
        address: 'amq.match',
        filter: {
            'foo': amqp_types.wrap_described({
                'nat': 'it',
                'prod': 'a22',
                'x-match': 'all'
            }, 0x468C00000002)
        }
    }
});
```

where:

```
var amqp_types = require('rhea').types;
```

That works only with Qpid cpp, it's not working with ActiveMQ and Qpid java.